# How does `private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream)` return an object in custom serialization in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm reading about [custom serialization](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization#3-custom-serialization-in-java) in Java, where you provide the following two methods inside the class that you want to serialize:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos)
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)
```

For example:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private transient Address address;
    private Person person;

    // setters and getters

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) 
      throws IOException {
        oos.defaultWriteObject();
        oos.writeObject(address.getHouseNumber());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) 
      throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ois.defaultReadObject();
        Integer houseNumber = (Integer) ois.readObject();
        Address a = new Address();
        a.setHouseNumber(houseNumber);
        this.setAddress(a);
    }
}
```

When you want to deserialize the serialized object of the class `Employee` as follows:

```
Employee e2 = (Employee) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

the Java virtual machine will call the `readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)` method defined in the class `Employee` instead of the `readObject()` of the `ObjectInputStream` class ([source](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/serializationapi.html#:%7E:text=The%20trick%20here%20is%20that%20the%20virtual%20machine%20will%20automatically%20check%20to%20see%20if%20either%20method%20is%20declared%20during%20the%20corresponding%20method%20call)). However, the former method doesn't return anything (`void`), unlike the latter method which returns an `Object` type (which should be casted).

So, **how do we still get the `Employee` object from the above custom deserialization process?**

Comment: I think I've done this before and iirc I cast / use `ObjectOutputStream` as a `DataOutputStream` and just write the individual fields to the stream.  Then on read I just use a `DataInputStream` and read and fill in each field.  Voila.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get any additional object as a result of this method - the `readObject` method is not static and to run this you need to have instance (let say of `Employee` class) and - it's your object.

Take a look at the example [from this tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/serialization/custom-serialization-readobject-writeobject/) - what you are doing there is actually setting fields of **this** object

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream aInputStream) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException 
{       
    firstName = aInputStream.readUTF();
    lastName = aInputStream.readUTF();
    accountNumber = aInputStream.readInt();
    dateOpened = new Date(aInputStream.readLong());
}
```

Comment: Ah, right.  If this is the problem, you don't create an additional object.  The object has already been created for you.  The `readObject` method is just filling in the specific instance fields for the object that was just created.

Comment: @m.antkowicz @markspace So, the object you mentioned (**this** object) is created by the JVM without using the constructor, and the `readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)` method of the `Employee` class is what sets the fields of that object?

Comment: I think that's a good summary.  There may be subtle differences in the implementation, but that's basically how I think of it.

Comment: That comment I don't believe is correct.  Certain types of serialization require a no-argument constructor, but the built-in serialization the JVM can just magic up an object with out using any constructor at all.

Comment: Ugh you are right it's just me doesn't know how to read... It's clearly written: `Have access to the no-arg constructor of its first nonserializable superclass` - sorry for this misleading, removed comment